# how to add add leading zeros to string value so that result is fixed length

Tags: c#

If I want to add x numbers of zeros to the left of a int I can use this...

```
        string fmt = "0000";
        int intValue = 4;
        Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString(fmt));
        Console.WriteLine();
```

This will give 0004 and is fine, but this does not work if intValue would be a string. Any ideas of how I can accomplish this with a string?

Comment: `String.PadLeft`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-pad-a-number-with-leading-zeros

Comment: `int intValue = int.Parse(strValue);`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(intValue.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0'));`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine($"{intValue:d4}");` to ensure **4** digits, e.g. `0012`